# Why cannot I connect to server(Java)? 403 Error Code returned

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I am developing Java Server`(Spring-boot)` with test client(Java script based).
but, when I try to connect to Server, client throws `403 Error` code(failed to load resources 403).

Is there anyone who solved this problem? 
I am bad at controlling Spring framework. I think Server site has problem, but I cannot find why it send `403 error` code.

Additionally, I created trust-store and key-store for using `https` and set the path in application.property. 
I also want to know if Server site's code is correct or not related to client site. Thank you.

My Server Code(Controlling)

```
@Log4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v0.1/login")
public class LoginSessionAPI {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String verify(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("pw") String pw) {

        String auth = service.excute(id, pw);

        return auth;
    }
}
```

Client Site(JavaScript)

```
function getService(userId, userPw, ipPort){

    var protocol = "https://"
    var HOST = protocol + ipPort + "/v0.1/login";
    console.log("HOST : "+HOST);
    var loginAuth;
    var loginJson = new Object();
    loginJson.id = userId;
    loginJson.pw = userPw;

    var loginRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();


    loginRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        // process the server response
        console.log("status : "+loginRequest.status);
        if (loginRequest.status == 200) {
            console.log("object : "+loginRequest.responseText);
            if(loginRequest.responseText === ""){

            }else{
                var responseLoginJson = eval("("+loginRequest.responseText+")");
                loginAuth = responseLoginJson.loginAuth;
            }

        } else {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    };
    loginRequest.open("POST", HOST, false);
    loginRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    console.log(loginJson);
    loginRequest.send(JSON.stringify(loginJson));
}



And then,
I call getService(id, pw, ipPort) function.
```

I created SSL Certification.
application.properties

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-password=123456
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.trust-store=cacerts.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=123456
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_25\u200C\u200B6_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
```

Comment: `403` is `Forbidden`, so you're not authorized.

Comment: How can I authorize for this?
I created trust-store and key-store and set path.